# Template Conversion Operator with SFINAE / Hiding

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, sfinae

I would like to use template conversion operators on different class-hierarchy levels. My problem is that even if SFINAE fails the base conversion operator is hidden.
Is there a workaround like using?

Sample code to illustrate the problem (std::is_same_v<TOther, bool> is just a sample):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct Bar
{
    template<typename T>
    operator T()
    {
        std::cout << "Bar::conv\n";
        return {};
    }
};

struct Foo : public Bar
{
    template<
        typename TOther,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<TOther, bool>>
    >
    operator TOther()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::conv\n";
        return {};
    }   
};

#include <iostream>
int main(){

    Foo f;

    bool b = f;

    //error: operator bool is hidden?
    int i = f;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, my only option is to delegate to the base class. But in this case I would need to duplicate the SFINAE checks...
(I need to be standard conformant)